# Windows Azure and System.Data.SQLite issues

Tags: c#, azure, system.data.sqlite

I am trying to locally test a Windows Azure (SDK 1.6) deployment on a Windows 7 x64 and I am getting the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

The web app worked fine outside of Azure environment but I am having huge troubles porting it to Azure due to `System.Data.SQLite`. The binary version is x64 so I wonder what could be wrong. I have come across [this blog post](http://www.fishofprey.com/2009/04/badimageformatexception-in-iis-70-on-64.html) but it is not helping.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: I trust you have verified that the `System.Data.SQLite` has been deployed with your application. I'm not thoroughly familiar with Azure (so the answer to this may be obvious), so have you verified that your Azure instance is running on x64 architecture?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, "Copy Local" was `False` but changing it to `True` did not help at all. I can't be 100% sure about local setup with Azure and x64 but I am sure Azure is x64 when deployed to a real thing. I have verified all "Azure" processes in the Task Manager and they all are 64-bit.

Comment: Hm... it seems this was a `Copy Local` issue after all. Unfortunately, it was not obvious because `System.Data.SQLite` is referenced in a library and obviously `Copy Local` is not very useful there. It needs to be set on the main project. @M.Babcock if you care to enter an answer, I'd be more than happy to accept it. Thanks!